# Remove elements from an array until there are just 10 elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects in Javascript that look like this:

```
[{width:100,height:50,name:"John"},{width:27,height:12,name:"John"},..]
```

If that Array size is bigger than 10, I would like to remove those objects which area (width*height) are smaller. So, if there are 20 objects, remove the 10 which area are smaller among the rest.

How could I do this?

Right now what I do is have a threshold in order to filter the objects. So I do this:

```
var i = elements.length;
var threshold = 100;
while (i--) {
  if (elements[i].width * elements[i].height < threshold) {
    elements.splice(i,1);
  }
}
```

But this is not what I want. I don't want a static threshold, I just want to remove those which area is smaller than the rest top 10.

Comment: @Zzyrk edited with what I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could sort the array and then set its length to 10.

```
var areas = [{width:100,height:50,name:"John"},{width:27,height:12,name:"John"},...];

areas.sort(function(a, b){ 
    return  b.height * b.width - a.height * a.width;
});

areas.length = 10;
```

Note that this only works if you don't care if the array elements get reordered.

http://jsfiddle.net/g9Hk7/

Comment: What would be the difference between doing areas.length or splice as dfsq answer suggested?

Comment: @HommerSmith, nothing, I just think setting the length is easier, clearer, and more concise.

Comment: @dfsq I actually started writing this before yours got posted, and considered not posting it, but I decided to keep it because of the simpler sort function. I think people sometimes forget that sort callbacks just have to return positive or negative, not +1 or -1.

Answer (score 10):

You can sort your array first by area and then use `slice` to leave only 10 bigger. Something like this:

```
var arr = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    var as = a.width * a.height,
        bs = b.width * b.height;
    if (as > bs) return -1;
    if (as < bs) return 1;
    return 0; 
})
.slice(0, 10);
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/y765Z/

Comment: just `return as - bs`

Comment: @dfsq I think your answer is awesome, and I upvoted it but I found Dagg Nabbit easier to understand. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: You are right, guys. @DaggNabbit your version is for sure more concise.

Comment: @HommerSmith Sure, I also find Dagg Nabbit's answer more clear.

Comment: @HommerSmith: note that assigning `.length` won't work right if the array is shorter than 10 items. `slice` is a cleaner way.

Answer (score 1):

One other possibility, if you need to keep them in order is this somewhat strange little bit here:

```
arr.map(function(item, index) {
    return {index: index, area: item.height * item.width};
}).sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.area - a.area;
}).slice(10).sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.index - a.index;
}).reduce(function(arr, item) {
    arr.splice(item.index, 1);
    return arr;
}, arr);
```

This modifies the original array, but you can change that by replacing the last line with

```
}, clone(arr));
```

using some appropriate clone function, perhaps this:

```
var clone = function(obj) {return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));};
```

Obviously if you wanted to turn this into a function, you could generalize the `10`, and it would pretty easy to abstract from `area` into an arbitrary function on your objects as well.